# Change value of an XML element

Tags: c#, xml, element

I'm trying to change the value of Xml elements :

```
<string id="68056"><![CDATA[Anti-Aliasing:]]></string>
<string id="68085"><![CDATA[V Sync:]]></string>
<string id="68100"><![CDATA[Frame Limit:]]></string>
<string id="68125"><![CDATA[Pixel Light Count:]]></string>
<string id="68162"><![CDATA[Shadow Cascades:]]></string>
<string id="68195"><![CDATA[* Game requires restart for changes to take effect *]]></string>
<string id="68300"><![CDATA[Video & Graphics]]></string>
<string id="68333"><![CDATA[Anti-Aliasing:   ]]></string>
<string id="68368"><![CDATA[Texture Quality: ]]></string>
<string id="68403"><![CDATA[Pixel Light Count: ]]></string>
<string id="68442"><![CDATA[Shadow Cascades: ]]></string>
<string id="68477"><![CDATA[Graphics]]></string>
<string id="68494"><![CDATA[AddonLoader: Exception iterating ']]></string>
```

I've got thousands of lines like those.
I want to change the values in the < !CDATA[ ...  ]> section, relatively to the **id** value. This is the void I made, but it doesn't work.

```
    public static void SetElement(int id, string text)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(File.OpenRead(PATH));
        foreach (XmlNode item in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (int.Parse(((XmlElement)item).GetAttribute("id")) == id)
            {
                doc.CreateCDataSection(text);
                doc.Save(PATH);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried using doc.DocumentElement.Value = text instead of doc.CreateCDataSection(text), it didn't work either.

Can you give me a working void, please ? :)

Comment: Should be GetAttribute("id").Value

Comment: @jdweng - it shouldn't, as that wouldn't compile. `GetAttribute` returns a `string` - [see the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest using LINQ to XML rather than the older `XmlDocument` model - it's a lot easier to work with.

```
public static void SetElement(int id, string text)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(PATH);

    var element = doc.Descendants()
        .Single(e => (int)e.Attribute("id") == id);

    element.ReplaceNodes(new XCData(text));

    doc.Save(PATH);
}
```

Though this code will work it's not ideal - you are parsing, searching and writing the whole document every time.  If you are going to change the contents of more than one element you should re-use the `XDocument` and only save once finished.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way using `XmlDocument` :

```
public static void SetElement(int id, string text)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(File.OpenRead(PATH));

    var xpath = String.Format("//*[@id='{0}']", id);
    var str = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    var cdata = (XmlCDataSection)str.FirstChild;
    cdata.InnerText = text;

    doc.Save(PATH);
}
```

Or if you can afford to switch to newer API, [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
public static void SetElement(int id, string text)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(PATH);
    var str = docx.Descendants()
                  .FirstOrDefault(o => (int?)o.Attribute("id") == id);
    var cdata = (XCData)str.FirstNode;
    cdata.Value = text;

    doc.Save(PATH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string parent =
                "<parent>" +
                   "<string id=\"68056\"><![CDATA[Anti-Aliasing:]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68085\"><![CDATA[V Sync:]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68100\"><![CDATA[Frame Limit:]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68125\"><![CDATA[Pixel Light Count:]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68162\"><![CDATA[Shadow Cascades:]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68195\"><![CDATA[* Game requires restart for changes to take effect *]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68300\"><![CDATA[Video & Graphics]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68333\"><![CDATA[Anti-Aliasing:   ]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68368\"><![CDATA[Texture Quality: ]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68403\"><![CDATA[Pixel Light Count: ]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68442\"><![CDATA[Shadow Cascades: ]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68477\"><![CDATA[Graphics]]></string>" +
                   "<string id=\"68494\"><![CDATA[AddonLoader: Exception iterating ']]></string>" +
                "</parent>";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(parent);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var results = doc.Root.Elements("string").OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("id").Value);

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: All this does it return all the elements.  If the requirement is to update the CDATA of a specific Id, how does this solve the problem?

Comment: It shows the proper syntax of getting the attribute "VALUE".

Comment: The value attribute returns is the string name "id", and not the value like 68056.